# Loading 3D volumes in tensorflow and then shuffling the data

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have around 100 ".hdf5" files. Each file has around 300 (variable) 3D volumes of size 80x80x80 belonging to same class. In total there are 100 classes. I have other data like image id and other data corresponding to each volume in all ".hdf5" files.

My problem is: how to split them to train, test, validate by shuffling them without loading the data into memory and then how to load data for training. I cannot load data in my RAM altogether as 3D volumes are consuming a lot of memory. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Some reading that might help you:

https://medium.com/tensorflow/an-introduction-to-biomedical-image-analysis-with-tensorflow-and-dltk-2c25304e7c13; check the part about "Using a TFRecords database"

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets  it's the original exhaustive guide from Tensorflow. Check the part "Consuming NumPy arrays". I'm not sure about your specific case, but this helps in general to have a good understanding of the loading process